# Image not found in ASP.NET MVC 3 in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I looked for a similar thread, and didn't find a solution. My problem is:

- I created an asp mvc 3 webpage in visual studio 2010
- I added pictures in the Content/Images to be used in one page
- I added a folder called swf, containing a flash file for another page

It all works when I run it in local host, the layouts .css and everything.

Problem:
When I put it in IIS

- .css doesn't display in SOME pages, not all of them
- The flash object doesn't appear, i'm suspecting it doesn't find it or something.

I read this is a common problem, but haven't found how to solve it, any help appreciated.

**Additional info**

Here are pieces from the code in various parts

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Green.cshtml";
}

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/history.css")" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/history.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/swfobject.js")"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">    
    var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";    
    var xiSwfUrlStr = "/swf/playerProductInstall.swf";    
    swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/QrCodeReader.swf", "flashContent", "350px", "350px", "10.0.0", xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);    
    swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");

<li><img src="/Content/Images/flower.png" width="700" height="300" alt="" /></li>
```

Comment: How are you referencing your css, image and flash files?  Can you include an example of some of the paths which aren't working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the `@Url.Content` syntax for the paths you're using within your javascript.  That will ensure the paths are created correctly regardless of how your virtual directories are setup.

```
var xiSwfUrlStr = '@Url.Content("~/swf/playerProductInstall.swf")';

swfobject.embedSWF('@Url.Content("~/swf/QrCodeReader.swf")', "flashContent", "350px", "350px", "10.0.0", xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);

<li><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flower.png")' width="700" height="300" alt="" /></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/flower.png") %>
```

That should definitely do it.

Answer (score 0):

fyi - download fiddler and you can easily what uris are being requested and your 404 errors.